# Clearing fields in the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have problem with clearing inputs. After I press submit and get proper response or I do refresh of the page the text I wrote before that stays in inputs. You can see the image at the end. How do I fixed this? What line is missing or I have some extra lines ??

PHP code:

```
<?php 

if (!empty($_POST['ime']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['adresa']) && !empty($_POST['grad'])
   && !empty($_POST['obrazovanje']) && !empty($_POST['osebi'])) {

       //ubacivanje u bazu
        $sql = "INSERT INTO zahtev (ime, email, adresa, grad, obrazovanje, osebi)
          VALUES ('".htmlspecialchars($_POST['ime'])."', '".htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])."', '".htmlspecialchars($_POST['adresa'])."', 
             '".htmlspecialchars($_POST['grad'])."',  '".htmlspecialchars($_POST['obrazovanje'])."', '".htmlspecialchars($_POST['osebi'])."')";

            if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
                echo "Podaci ubaceni.";     
            } else   
                { echo "Greska"; }
        }


       // definisanje promenjivih i postavaljanje vrednosti polja
$imeErr = $emailErr = $adresaErr = $gradErr = $obrazovanjeErr = $polErr = $osebiErr = "";
$ime = $email = $adresa = $grad = $obrazovanje = $pol = $osebi = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["ime"])) {
     $imeErr = "Ime i prezime je obavezno polje";
   } else {
     $ime = test_input($_POST["ime"]);
     // proveri da li ime sadrzi samo slova i prazna polja
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$ime)) {
       $imeErr = "Dozvoljena su samo slova"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email je obavezno polje";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // proveri da li je email ispravan 
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Pogresan email"; 
     }
   }

      if (empty($_POST["adresa"])) {
     $adresaErr = "Adresa  je obavezno polje";
   } else {
     $adresa = test_input($_POST["adresa"]);
     // proveri da li adresa sadrzi samo slova, brojeve i prazna polja
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$adresa)) {
       $adresaErr = "Dozvoljena su samo slova"; 
     }
   }

     if (empty($_POST["grad"])) {
     $gradErr = "Grad  je obavezno polje";
   } else {
     $grad = test_input($_POST["grad"]);
     // proveri da li grad sadrzi samo slova i prazna polja
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$grad)) {
       $gradErr = "Dozvoljena su samo slova"; 
     }
   }

    if (empty($_POST["obrazovanje"])) {
     $obrazovanjeErr = "Grad  je obavezno polje";
   } else {
     $obrazovanje = test_input($_POST["grad"]);
     // proveri da li obrazovanje sadrzi samo slova i prazna polja
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$obrazovanje)) {
       $obrazovanjeErr = "Dozvoljena su samo slova"; 
     }
   }

      if (empty($_POST["pol"])) {
     $polErr = "Pol je obavezno polje";
   } else {
     $pol = test_input($_POST["pol"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["osebi"])) {
     $osebiErr = "Obavezno polje";
   } else {
     $osebi = test_input($_POST["osebi"]);
     // proveri da li polje o sebi sadrzi samo slova i prazna polja
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$osebi)) {
       $osebiErr = "Dozvoljena su samo slova"; 
     }
   }

}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}        

?>
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Zahtev za clanstvo</title>
      <!-- <script>
        function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("podaci").reset();  }
       </script> -->
 </head>
 <body>

<form  method="post" id = "podaci" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <input type="text" name="ime"  value="<?php echo $ime;?>" id = "ime" placeholder = "Ime i prezime:*"/>
    <span><?php echo $imeErr;?></span>
    <br><br>

    <input type="text" name="email" id = "email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" placeholder = "Email:*"/>
    <span><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    <br><br>

    <input type="text" name="adresa" id = "adresa" value="<?php echo $adresa;?>" placeholder = "Adresa:*"/>
    <span> <?php echo $adresaErr;?></span>
    <br><br>

    <input type="text" name="grad" id = "grad" value="<?php echo $grad;?>" placeholder = "Grad:*"/>
    <span><?php echo $gradErr;?></span>
    <br><br>

    <input type="text" name="obrazovanje" id = "obrazovanje" value="<?php echo $obrazovanje;?>" placeholder = "Obrazovanje:*"/>
    <span><?php echo $obrazovanjeErr;?></span>
    <br><br>

    <input type="radio" name="pol" <?php if (isset($pol) && $pol=="female") echo "checked";?>  value="zenski">Zenski
    <input type="radio" name="pol" <?php if (isset($pol) && $pol=="male") echo "checked";?>  value="muski">Muski
    <span> <?php echo $polErr;?></span>
    <br><br>

    <input id = "dan" list="dan" name="dan" placeholder = "Dan rodjenja:*">
      <datalist id="dan">
        <option value="01">
        <option value="02">
        <option value="03">
        <option value="04">
        <option value="05">
        <option value="06">
        <option value="07">
        <option value="08">
        <option value="09">
        <option value="10">
        <option value="11">
        <option value="12">
        <option value="13">
        <option value="14">
        <option value="15">
        <option value="16">
        <option value="17">
        <option value="18">
        <option value="19">
        <option value="20">
        <option value="21">
        <option value="22">
        <option value="23">
        <option value="24">
        <option value="25">
        <option value="26">
        <option value="27">
        <option value="28">
        <option value="29">
        <option value="30">
        <option value="31">
      </datalist>

    <input list="mesec" name="mesec" placeholder = "Mesec rodjenja:*">
        <datalist id = "mesec">
             <option value="Januar">
             <option value="Februar">
             <option value="Mart">
             <option value="April">
             <option value="Maj">
             <option value="Jun">
             <option value="Jul">
             <option value="Avgust">
             <option value="Septembar">
             <option value="Oktobar">
             <option value="Novembar">
             <option value="Decembar">
        </datalist>

    <input list="godina" name="godina" placeholder = "Godina rodjenja:*"><br><br>
        <datalist id = "godina">
            <option value="1970">
            <option value="1971">
            <option value="1972">
            <option value="1973">
            <option value="1974">
            <option value="1975">
            <option value="1976">
            <option value="1977">
            <option value="1978">
            <option value="1979">
            <option value="1980">
            <option value="1981">
            <option value="1982">
            <option value="1983">
            <option value="1984">
            <option value="1985">
            <option value="1986">
            <option value="1987">
            <option value="1988">
            <option value="1989">
            <option value="1990">]
            <option value="1991">
            <option value="1992">
            <option value="1993">
            <option value="1994">
            <option value="1995">
            <option value="1996">
            <option value="1997">
            <option value="1998">
            <option value="1999">
            <option value="2000">
        </datalist>


   <textarea name="osebi" rows="5" cols="15" id = "osebi" value="<?php echo $osebi;?>" placeholder = "O sebi:*"></textarea>
   <span><?php echo $osebiErr;?></span>
   <br><br>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Posalji" class="button" />
 <!--  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form"> -->

</form>


 </body>
 </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [reset()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp) for that, when the page loads again.

```
document.getElementById("podaci").reset();
```

Comment: Wait... you had it, but it's commented. Why? You could use the php to check if you want to print the js or not as you like.

Comment: i used that line you wrote .... i commented because it doesnt work for me ... i entered the informations pressed submit and that info still stands .... and i connected with my submit button ... but i will try again ... thank you ...

Comment: You must call the js after your form, calling it before won't work. Or let it be inside the function there and call the function after your form. Just like the "reset form" button you commented does. Or the button isn't working either?

Comment: ok i know that about place of thr function ... but 1st five fields doesnt get reseted even i do things like you said ... it just stays there ... even after i submit and refresh thet last input stays in fields ...

Comment: ty for your help ... problem was in this line value="<?php echo $name_of_the_variable;?>" ... of course for the all inputs where I put it ... now is working fine ...

Answer (score 0):

```
function emptyForm(){
    var form = document.getElementBy('myForm');
    for(var input in form.children) input.value='';
    for(var select in form.children) select.selectedIndex = 42; // replace 42 with whatever you want, you can also use something else then selectedIndex.
}
```

You can try this.

If you want other elements to be cleared as well but you can't figure it out,

just drop a comment.

Comment: ty for your help ... problem was in this line value="<?php echo $name_of_the_variable;?>" ... of course for the all inputs where I put it ... now is working fine ...